# Change the order of nodes in a Xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I would like to change odrer of some nodes in a XMl file.  Could someone please tell me how I can implement that.

my Xml look like this :

```
<magicdraw>
<diagram>
<fragment>
<message id="AA22"/>
<message id="AF32"/>
<message id="CD52"/>
<combinedfragment id="LL43"/>
</fragment>
</diagram>
</magicdraw>
```

I wanna change it to:

```
<magicdraw>
<diagram>
<fragment>
<message id="AA22"/>
<combinedfragment id="LL43"/>
<message id="AF32"/>
<message id="CD52"/>
</fragment>
</diagram>
</magicdraw>
```

Comment: It's a little difficult to know what you're after when you only present a single sample *and* fail to put any narrative around it. I.e. are we allowed to assume that the `id` values are fixed?, and there will only ever be these four elements? If not, more samples and/or some explanation of the *types* of input that will be received and what the transformation is would be useful. E.g. is what you've shown "move elements with ids `AF32` and `CD52` below the element with id `LL43`" or "move element `LL43` below element `AA22`"?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply iterate through your list box items, identify the corresponding 'node' element and AppendChild it, that way you should end up with the proper order as doing AppendChild on a node already inserted somewhere moves it around and you would move any node to its proper position:

```
XmlDocument nodeDoc = new XmlDocument();
linksDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("App_Data/Node.xml"));


foreach (ListItem li in lb1.Items)
{
  string itemId = li.Value;

  XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("/root/node[@id = '{0}']", itemId));
  if (node != null)
  {
    node.ParentNode.AppendChild(node);
  }
}
```